# I want to add a sub element to my menu items in jQuery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a menu item with jQuery and CSS. When I go to a one menu item I want to go for another sub menu item as shown in below image. How can I do that?

[image]

Here is my html markup

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_j.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <div class="content">
        <ul id="sdt_menu" class="sdt_menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="SlideDownBoxMenu2/images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Home</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">Home</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="SlideDownBoxMenu2/images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">File Managements</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">File Managements</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            <div class="sdt_box">
                        <a href="#"><img src="SlideDownBoxMenu2/images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Retention</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">Retention</span>
                    </span> </a>
                        <a href="#">Illustrations</a>
                        <a href="#">Photography</a>
                    <div class="sdt_box">

                        <a href="#">Retentionss </a>
                        <a href="#">Illustrations</a>
                        <a href="#">Photography</a>

                </div> 
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="SlideDownBoxMenu2/images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Portfolio</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">My work</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <div class="sdt_box">
                        <a href="#">Websites</a>
                        <a href="#">Illustrations</a>
                        <a href="#">Photography</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="SlideDownBoxMenu2/images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Portfolio</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">My work</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <div class="sdt_box">
                        <a href="#">Websites</a>
                        <a href="#">Illustrations</a>
                        <a href="#">Photography</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="SlideDownBoxMenu2/images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Portfolio</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">My work</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <div class="sdt_box">
                        <a href="#">Websites</a>
                        <a href="#">Illustrations</a>
                        <a href="#">Photography</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="SlideDownBoxMenu2/images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Portfolio</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">My work</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <div class="sdt_box">
                        <a href="#">Websites</a>
                        <a href="#">Illustrations</a>
                        <a href="#">Photography</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="SlideDownBoxMenu2/images/6.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">Projects</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">I like to code</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <div class="sdt_box">
                    <a href="#">Job Board Website</a>
                    <a href="#">Shopping Cart</a>
                    <a href="#">Interactive Maps</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div>
    <span class="reference">

    </span>
    </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
ul.sdt_menu{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
    font-family:"Myriad Pro", "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    width:1020px;
}
ul.sdt_menu a{
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;

}
ul.sdt_menu li{
    float:left;
    width:138px;
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}
ul.sdt_menu li > a{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:138px;
    height:57px;
    z-index:12;

    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
}
ul.sdt_menu li a img{
    border:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:57px;
    z-index:100;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;
}
ul.sdt_menu li span.sdt_wrap{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:0px;
    width:138px;
    height:57px;
    z-index:15;
}
ul.sdt_menu li span.sdt_active{
    position:absolute;
    background:#111;
    top:57px;
    width:138px;
    height:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:14;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
}
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_link,
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_descr,
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a{
    margin-left:10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
    margin-top:-10px;
}
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_link{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:14px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_descr{
    color:#0B75AF;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    width:155px; /*For dumbass IE7*/
    font-size:10px;
    letter-spacing:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:-8px;
}
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:138px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:138px;
    top:57px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
    background:#000;
}
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a{
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    line-height:30px;
    color:#0B75AF;
}
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a:first-child{
    margin-top:15px;
}
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a:hover{
    color:#fff;
}
```

Here is my Javascript code with jQuery:

```
   <!-- The JavaScript -->

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                /**
                * for each menu element, on mouseenter, 
                * we enlarge the image, and show both sdt_active span and 
                * sdt_wrap span. If the element has a sub menu (sdt_box),
                * then we slide it - if the element is the last one in the menu
                * we slide it to the left, otherwise to the right
                */
                $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
                    var $elem = $(this);
                    $elem.find('img')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({
                            'width':'138px',
                            'height':'57px',
                            'left':'0px'
                         },400,'easeOutBack')
                         .andSelf()
                         .find('.sdt_wrap')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({'top':'140px'},500,'easeOutBack')
                         .andSelf()
                         .find('.sdt_active')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({'height':'138px'},300,function(){
                        var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                        if($sub_menu.length){
                            var left = '138px';
                            if($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index()+1)
                                left = '-138px';
                            $sub_menu.show().animate({'left':left},200);
                        }   
                    });
                }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                    var $elem = $(this);
                    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                    if($sub_menu.length)
                        $sub_menu.hide().css('left','0px');

                    $elem.find('.sdt_active')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({'height':'0px'},300)
                         .andSelf().find('img')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({
                            'width':'0px',
                            'height':'0px',
                            'left':'85px'},400)
                         .andSelf()
                         .find('.sdt_wrap')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({'top':'25px'},500);
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Why don't you just organize it all into one list?

Comment: Hello now check to this and do http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/3qPbE/11/

Answer (score 0):

I would advise continuing with unordered lists, like you're doing with the top-level nav items. No reason to switch it up when you go down the heirarchy; it only complicates your code. If you do want to keep what you have now, I would advise (I'm going to use *My Work > Websites* as an example, as shown in your image) putting the link inside of a container of some sort, and then put the initially hidden sub-menu in that container as well. That way, you can target the sub-menu easily when the link is clicked on, or hovered over, with something like this:

```
<!-- just a snippet -->
            <span class="sdt_descr">My work</span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <div class="sdt_box">
        <div class="nameThisSomethingMeaningful">
            <href="#">Websites</a>
            <div class="hiddenSubmenu">
                <a href="amazingthingImade.com">Amazing Website</a>
                <!-- more links here -->
            </div>
        <div>
        <div class="nameThisSomethingMeaningful">
            <a href="#">Illustrations</a>
            <div class="hiddenSubmenu">
                <a href="mysite.com/illustration/client1">Client Work 1</a>
                <!-- more links here -->
            </div>
       <div>
<!-- etc. etc. -->

<!-- now the JS -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".sdt_box a").on("click", function(){ // feel free to use mouseenter or mouseleave, or w/e
    $(this).parent().find(".hiddenSubmenu").fadeIn();
  });
});
</script>
```

But like I said, your life could be made a lot simpler in the future if you treat each level of the navigation the same. You're already using <li>s for your top-level nav; I would have just continued as such, because they have a natural heirarchy, and you won't have to mess with all that .parent()/.find()/.child()/etc DOM traversal. Here's how I'd go about it:

```
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <ul class="subMenu">
          <li><a href="#">Websites</a>
            <ul class="subSubMenu">
              <li><a href="...">Client 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="...">Client 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="...">Client 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Illustration</a>
            <ul class="subSubMenu">
              <li><a href="...">Client 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="...">Client 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="...">Client 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>    
      <li><a href="#">Some Other Menu</a>
        <ul class="subMenu">
          <li><a href="#">Some Other Submenu</a>
            <ul class="subSubMenu">
              <li><a href="...">Client 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="...">Client 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="...">Client 3</a></li>
              <!--etc.-->
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Single item, no submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

You'll basically use very similar, if not the same, Javascript as what I wrote above, and let CSS do all the placement. The important part here is going to be using *relative* and *absolute* positioning to communicate the existing heirarchy visually.

It looks like you know your way around CSS, but for completion's sake, this is (a very rough quick version of) how I'd replicate the layout you have, plus the third-level subMenu floating to the right of the item in question (*Websites* in this case):

```
/* basic boilerplate stuff */
* {  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
a {
  color: #aaa;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* end of boilerplate */

nav li {
  transition-duration: .3s;
  list-style-type: none; /*get rid of bullets*/
}

nav > ul > li {
  display: inline; /* top-level menu, lay out horizontally */
  position: relative;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  
  width: 180px;
  height: 80px;

  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.subMenu > li, .subSubMenu > li { 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  position: relative;
}
.subMenu > li a, .subSubMenu > li a {
  padding: .5em .75em;
}

.subMenu, .subSubMenu {
  display: none; /* hidden until hover/click (JS) */
  position: absolute; /* also absolutely essential for position under parent item */
  
  width: 300px;
}
nav li:hover {
  background-color: royalblue;
}
.subMenu {
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  
  background-color: #777;
}
.subSubMenu {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
}
.subSubMenu a {
  color: #555;
}
nav li.hasSub:after {
  content: '\25ba';
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: .5em;
  top: auto;
  bottom: auto;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the result]

Here's the source, with more complete JS than my quick example above, using mouseenter and mouseleave instead of click: https://replit.com/@GordonZed/Quik-n-Dirty-List-Nav?v=1

Just click "view code" at the top right.